# jointjs rewrite jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jointjs

we are using jquery v2.1.0, app.js and joint.js v0.8.0 in this order.
However in joint.js v0.8.0, the jQuery function is being replaced by v1.9.1.

Is there any way to make joint.js use the included jquery in my application?
Or prevent it to replace the jQuery function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `joint.js` [source code](http://www.jointjs.com/downloads/joint.js) you can clearly see that it's including jQuery in it's own code.

What you can do is not include jquery yourself then and let `joint.js` include it for you.

Comment: If you look at the list of `joint.js` bundles at https://github.com/DavidDurman/joint/tree/master/dist then there seems to be also `joint.nojquery.min.js` version which OP could use instead of the `joint.min.js`. Do you see a problem with using this bundle?

Comment: @xmojmr Probably should use `joint.nojquerynobackbone.min.js` then. I don't know what's the point of this but plugin author should just specify dependency on jQuery + Backbone and include his plain script. It's just confusing otherwise..